# Is autoescape off in django safe?

Tags: django, templates

I want to display some HTML in `Django 1.0` templates and to do that I have been doing something like this:

```
{% autoescape off %}{{ var.text }}{% endautoescape %}
```

and I am just wondering how safe this is?  Am I still protected against SQL injection and cross-site scripting and other vulnerabilities like that?

**Update:**

This text will be coming from users, so what is the best way to display HTML in a Django template safely?

Answer (score 13):

No, when you mark your HTML as safe in the template engine, you are taking the responsibility to sure it's safe to render.

Also, you can simplify (well, shorten) your code a little by changing

```
{% autoescape off %}
    {{ var.text }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

to

```
{{ var.text|safe }}
```

Answer (score 11):

The autoescape would be a protection against cross site scripting, not sql injection (which you need to [make sure your inputs are scrubbed](http://www.djangobook.com/en/beta/chapter20/)). Turning autoescape off would mean you trust what is in "text", wherever it came from, not to be malicious, (ie, it should be impossible for a user to create or modify what is in text). If that assumption is valid, then you are safe against cross site scripting, otherwise, that is a security hole.

Comment: I edited my questions above: "This text will be coming from users, so what is the best way to display html in a django template safely?"

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not this is safe depends entirely on where var.text came from.  If it is a promotional message (for example) that is entirely in your control, then you're safe as long as you don't shoot yourself in the foot.  If var.text somehow came from a user, then you are in danger.